# Research proposal for postdoc applications

Tags: application, postdocs

I am a final year PhD student in Physics applying for postdoc. Usually institutes ask for statement of research in postdoc applications. But one of them asks for a research proposal (less than two pages). I already have a four page long research statement. I was thinking of omitting my past research part (I'll not be working on my thesis related work in future). Can someone suggest me how to modify a statement of research to make that a research proposal.

Comment: Sea for example https://chroniclevitae.com/news/820-research-statements-versus-research-proposals There are also other useful website that you can refer to.

Answer (score 7):

My recommendation is to not modify your research statement, but just write the research proposal from the beginning.  It's less than 2 pages, so it's not that much work, and depending on how your research proposal is written, the result probably won't flow well if you just delete the previous work parts.

Comment: I know this is probably no longer relevant for you, but I thought I'd give an answer for future generations...

Comment: I thought Research proposals usually never contain previous work-related stuff (in the usual case, i.e. if the person is not switching the field etc).